# How to add string to file at server side using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, webix

I am trying to save values taken from webix textarea to file at server, but no luck for now.
I could do it eaqsily with php:

```
$filename = getcwd() . "/test.txt";
echo $filename;
$line_i_am_looking_for = 5;
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
$lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = '6my modified line';
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
?>
```

But I don't know how to do it with AJAX.
What I need is - take value from textarea, insert it to (for e.g.) 6th string of data/data.php file.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Loading from DB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codebase/webix.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="codebase/webix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $filename = getcwd() . "/test.txt";
      echo $filename;
      $line_i_am_looking_for = 5;
      $lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
      $lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = '6my modified line';
      file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
    ?>

    <div class='header_comment'>Test Button</div>
    <div id="testB" style='height:600px'></div>
    <hr>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      webix.ready(function() {
        gridb = webix.ui({
          container: "testB",
          "view": "form",
          "elements": [
            {
              "view": "textarea",
              "name": "woNumber",
              "id": "textarea",
              "label": "",
              "width": 300,
              "height": 200,
              "options": [
                "onViewResize"
              ],
              "value": "",
              "placeholder": "WO number (separate with comma if several)",
              "labelPosition": "top"
            },
            {
              "view": "button",
              "name": "getWODetails",
              "label": "",
              "value": "Submit",
              "options": [
                "autowidth:true"
              ],
              on: {
                onItemClick: function(id) {
                  webix.message("Sikim BLEAT'!!!");
                }
              },
              "labelPosition": "top"
            },
            {
              "view": "button",
              "id": "button1",
              "name": "getWODetails",
              "label": "",
              "value": "Passss",
              "options": [
                "autowidth:true"
              ],
              on: {
                onItemClick: function() {
                  webix.message("Values of textarea is " + $$('textarea').getValue());
                }
              },
              "labelPosition": "top"
            }
          ]
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I want to do is once I click Passs button, it takes values from textarea and save it in 6th string of data/data.php file. All I could do for now is to extract value from textarea )))))

data/data.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
require_once("../samples/common/connector/data_connector.php‌​"); 
//!connector 
$dbtype = "MySQL"; 
$username = "roman"; 
$password = "Pass"; 
$hostname = "111.111.111.111"; 
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL"); 
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>"; 
$data = new JSONDataConnector($conn,$dbtype); 
$data->render_sql("SELECT SITE_ID, 3G_SITE_ID 
                   FROM MASTER_TRACKER_DB.MASTER_TRACKER 
                   WHERE SITE_ID LIKE '%ABK000%'", "", "SITE_ID, 3G_SITE_ID"); 
?>
```

Comment: What does `test.txt` look like?

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly data/data.php looks like this: 

`<?php
require_once("../samples/common/connector/data_connector.php"); 
$dbtype = "MySQL";
$username = "roman";
$password = "Pass";
$hostname = "111.111.111.111"; 

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";



$data = new JSONDataConnector($conn,$dbtype);

$data->render_sql("SELECT SITE_ID, 3G_SITE_ID FROM MASTER_TRACKER_DB.MASTER_TRACKER WHERE SITE_ID LIKE '%ABK000%'", "", "SITE_ID, 3G_SITE_ID");


?>`

Comment: I actually asked to see **`test.txt`**

Comment: @RiggsFolly test.txt is just test file and contain like few symbols per string.